# Strange TextBox behavior using AutoCompleteMode.Append: Ctrl+A clears the text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I use `AutoCompleteMode` set to `AutoCompleteMode.Append` in TextBox control.
After the auto-complete feature appends text to the existing and selects it, if I press <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> to select all the text, the textBox is cleared.

It happens with any textbox, you can test it by your own.
Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be annoying, if you use this shortcut, that is.
That combination is *intercepted* along the way and misbehaves when `AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append`. You can see it when a word in the list is partially selected; press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (the <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> equivalent here) to select it all, then press <kbd>END</kbd> and <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>: the text Selection wasn't actually cleared, the last letter is *magically* re-selected instead of deleted.

As a simple workaround, you can suppress the key presses when you detect that combination and use `SelectAll()` to select the text yourself:
<sub>(as noted, pressing `Enter` would to the same thing)</sub>

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
    End If
End Sub
```