# TextBox Autocompletion - Prevent automatic submit(Keydown with Keycode.Enter) when clicking suggested item

Tags: c#, winforms, events, autocomplete, textbox

Hello I've a TextBox with Autocompletion source & mode set up in a winform. Now i've the problem that with clicking a suggestion, it will also trigger KeyDown event with Keycode.Enter, leading into weird behavior.

Can i somehow prevent to trigger the event at all when clicking a suggestion from autocomplete dropdown?

Currently in the keydown event i check if the autocomplete source contains what is written into the textbox, but with this, a user also can't submit anymore by enter if he just wants to send the suggested text anyway.

```
private void tbInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            tbInput.SelectAll();
        }


        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            if (tbInput.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Contains(tbInput.Text) && tbInput.Text.EndsWith(" "))
            {
                tbInput.SelectionStart = tbInput.Text.Length;
                return;
            }
            btnSend_Click(sender, null);
        }
    }
```

What i did here is, that autocompletesource entries with a space at the end (awaiting a parameter) will not send. Others will send anyway. But i want none to send without the user confirming the selected suggestion, while keeping the general logic to send commands by pressing Enter.

//EDIT
I've added a github repo for testing: https://github.com/WaGi-Coding/AutocompleteIssue

// Solved by comment from Jimi
Also when autocomplete appends & i press Ctrl+A, it will delete all text, instead of selecting everything. Thats only the case if you continue on from the appended text, if you add 1 more character, delete it again and press Ctrl+A, it behaves like expected. But the bigger problem for me is the first issue above.
//////////////////////////////

Should i use some library instead? Is there some better way to modify how it behaves?

Any help would be appreciated. Greetings

Comment: You should post the code related to the KeyDown event. Usually, the first thing you do when you receive `Keys.Enter` is to suppress the Key. Not sure why you check what has been entered in the TextBox, given that you want to *send the suggested text anyway* (?) -- In relation to the `CTRL+A` behavior and AutoComplete, see [Strange TextBox behavior using AutoCompleteMode.Append: Ctrl+A clears the text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62204679/7444103)

Comment: Thanks @Jimi the Ctrl+A problem is solved ♥

Regarding the other problem: I've added some code to show my current "workaround" with some more explanation.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't see what's the use of that code in the KeyDown handler: if a user presses Enter, then you process the input (if not empty), if the AutoComplete kicks in, you process the input anyway. Possibly, pass the input string to a method which is not another event handler, as in `btnSend_Click(sender, null);`. Write a method that both the KeyDown handler and `btnSend` call when needed. If you want/need to verify whether the input is part of the AutoComplete collection (using the source of this property), do that after and act on it as needed. Use an ErrorProvider object for the notifications.

Comment: I've added this because it triggers KeyDown when clicking a suggestion in the dropdown. And i want to get rid of the autocomplete triggering the KeyDown event at all. What i did there is a temp solution, which has it's own problems. Unfortunately i don't know how i'd implement what you describe, or if my problem is clear enough. Basically i just want to put clicked suggestions in the textbox, without the keydown to fire. I was hoping for a event or something triggered when selecting a suggestion. I just realized it's triggering Keydown with Enter, bc i've the Send functionality already

Comment: Then describe the real problem and not how you planned to solve it. What is the problem related to the Enter key triggering when a user selects a value? It's there on purpose, so you know that a selection has been made. It's not clear why it gets in the way and in the way of what.

Comment: Also it does not check if empty, it checks if it ends with a Space, as part of my solution. If a source-entry ends with SPACE, i do not send it, as it expects a parameter. While it sends others instantly. I won't have the others send instantly, but keep the sending functionality with pressing enter.

Why does it even trigger KeyDown with Enter when selecting a suggestion? I do not understand this behavior

Comment: Then you need to describe what you're actually processing and what your code is actually doing after that. If you want to override the default functionality, then it's a custom implementation that is related to the use case. Without a clear use case...

Comment: I've added a Github Repo with a simple example. Check the AutoCompleteCustomSource of the textbox to see which "commands" are available for testing  
https://github.com/WaGi-Coding/AutocompleteIssue

Comment: I don't see what the issue is. Do you want to prevent a User from selecting a *command* that is not in the AutoComplete list? Or what else? As mentioned, you need to clearly, explicitly, specify what is your code meant to achieve and what is the related use-case. Without this information, it's not possible to determine what's failing, since it appears that the procedure works as intended. So, instead of saying what you don't want, say what you actually want to happen when a selection is made.

Comment: I want the user being able to edit the command after he clicked it in the suggestion-dropdown, instead of instantly sending it. So he always has to confirm with a press on enter to send, after suggestion is put in the input textbox.  I've tried it with a boolean, but then he has to press enter twice for non-suggested commands.

Comment: I've found this:  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12056856/11519208  

This at least let's me prevent raising it when it's clicked with the mouse, still, there is the Enter press issue :(

Comment: You don't need that, you can handle `PreviewKeyDown` instead of `KeyDown`, it's not triggered when you select an element from the list using the Mouse. The Enter key is still pressed if an element is selected using the Enter key, since the Focus is still on the TextBox. -- This is usually avoided using `AutoCompleteMode = Append`, so the User can still parse the elements in the List (with the Up-Down keys) without the IAutoComplete dropdown. -- I think I have already handled this somewhere. When I have a moment I'll take a look.

Comment: thanks, this way i'd not need to use user32.dll import.

It would be great. This bugs me since some days now ^^  
Append is no option for me, as autocomplete is pretty useless with a huge source with similar entries.  
  
I've found this, it was never solved either. So it seems the Autocomplete stuff is pretty old and has not changed much over years.
https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?545270-2005-Autocomplete-fires-KeyUp-event-with-Enter

Comment: If i could just detect if the suggestion dropdown is opened when pressing enter would be great, then i can just skip it if it's opened.

Comment: The only ways I know to detect the `IAutoCompleteDowndown` existence is to either implement the `IAutoComplete2` Interface directly (which I won't recommend just for this), or call `EnumThreadWindows` to check whether the Dropdown *is up*. Unfortunately (in a way :) UI Automation cannot detect that kind of Window. -- I gave it a look and I actually have a procedure for that, but you don't want to see it (it implements IAutoComplete2, IAutoComplete, IAutoCompleteDropDown..). This one could help you: [Detect when TextBox autocomplete list is showing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40915048/7444103)

Comment: I've tested it (it's Reza Aghaei's, it's already tested for sure, but... :) and it works as it is, as expected. -- There's also a C# *translation* just below it. -- Of course you don't need a Timer, just a method that calls `EnumThreadWindows` and returns true/false when you detect the Enter key press.

Comment: thanks a lot @Jimi

I don't understand why they made it that way. Triggering a key event if needed would have been easier :(